# How to save Excel file in Android app

Tags: android, excel

I want to save an Excel file in my Android APK, so it can be used after the apk is installed on an Android mobile device.
I want to do it from Android Studio.
Should I put it in the "assets" folder or is this used for different kinds of files to save?
I want to use it for updating my default database.

Comment: Put either in `raw` or `assets`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, it should go into your res/raw directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should indead put that exel file in assets folder.

The place to go with.

Answer (score 0):

Things like that are saved inside [R.raw](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.raw.html)

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)